# hexdump(): A memory layout utility to help debugging / understanding / optimising of C++ memory model

Tags: c++, memory-optimization

**EDIT**: Refer [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236058/212940) for improved solution with incorporated feedback and extended functionality. eg Automatically `hexdump` both parts of a stack/heap obj like `std::string`.

---

### Inspiration / Motivation

Modern C++, certainly compared to C, provides a lot of abstractions which protects us from / hide from us the details of memory allocation and layout. Mostly "we don't care about the detail", or shouldn't. But sometimes we do for these reasons:

- New to C++: Should understand differences between stack & heap and have some simple appreciation about memory layout. Polymorphism?
- Debug and inspect your application, especially if you're doing something a bit unusual. Getting a clear picture of "what is happening in memory" can be helpful. Yes the debugger can provide that, but the commands can be obscure and it's hard to get an overview. Also, I can compile the code below without `-g` and with `-O3` and it will not give me "optimized out" messages in the debugger. This is because the compiler "is aware of" the need to inspect the memory. (On the flip side we are changing what we are measuring here).
- Advanced optimisations like `struct` packing, or CPU cache line optimisations.

Before I go on: credit to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/165120/212940) and particularly [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/165162/212940). They provided the idea and first cut of my code came from that answer.

### `hd(adr, size)`: Show me the memory, quick!

Rather than battle a debugger, which is yet another abstraction, the idea is just to dump/inspect with:

```
std::cout << hd(&var, sizeof(var));
```

Sneak preview of the simple output (more interesting examples below):

```
0x405000: -- -- -- -- 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 00 --  | ....1234567890.
```

- We get the address (is it stack/heap/.text ?)
- The output is aligned to nearest 16 byte boundary => cache line? Padding between members or objects? (Most cache lines are 64 bytes, but that's too wide in terminal. Change one constant or make it a param is possibility).
- Hex and (printable) ASCII. Nothing new here.

The first 2 features are new over the related question / answer linked to above. In my opinion they broaden the use case significantly. **Refer comments in `main()`**.

### The Code

**Alert**: Some of the code may hurt your eyes. I have tried to keep it C++'ish and tried (and failed) not to use too many `reinterpret_casts`. I have tried to avoid (too much) UB, and hopefully succeeded. But probably not. In the end, realistically, it's `C` really...?

**Some features**

- `struct ostream_state` should be self explanatory and could be more generally useful. Tried to keep this generic => templated.
- main function `hex_dump()` is a bit long, but has just 3 three (linked) stages. I decided not to split.
- Using the "evil" `void*` was a choice suggested by previous answer and I decided to stick with it for this application.
- Lots of pointer arithmetic and hence lots of `// NOLINT` to shut up `clang-tidy`. I have looked behind each of those, and I think they are all OK.
- **Refer comments in main for demo of what I found interesting and useful in the output**
- Caveat: Output will obviously differ per machine (incl the SBO limit).

**Feedback wanted**:

- I find this useful, but is it?
- Usual trawl for bugs / UB (oh oh!) / cleaner techniques or structure

```
#include <bits/stdint-intn.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// utility: keeps states of an ostream, restores on destruction
template <typename T>
struct ostream_state {
  explicit ostream_state(std::basic_ostream<T>& stream)
      : stream_{stream}, flags_{stream.flags()}, fill_{stream.fill()}, width_{stream.width()} {}

  ostream_state(const ostream_state& other) = delete;
  ostream_state& operator=(const ostream_state& other) = delete;

  ostream_state(ostream_state&& other) = delete;
  ostream_state& operator=(ostream_state&& other) = delete;

  ~ostream_state() {
    stream_.flags(flags_);
    stream_.fill(fill_);
    stream_.width(width_);
  }

private:
  std::basic_ostream<T>&                    stream_;
  std::ios_base::fmtflags                   flags_;
  typename std::basic_ostream<T>::char_type fill_;
  std::streamsize                           width_;
};

inline std::ostream& print_ptr(std::ostream& os, const void* ptr) {
  auto state = ostream_state(os);
  return os << std::setw(19) << std::setfill(' ') << ptr; // NOLINT
}

inline std::ostream& print_byte(std::ostream& os, const unsigned char* ptr) {
  auto state = ostream_state(os);
  return os << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned>(*ptr) << ' ';
}

inline std::ostream& hex_dump(std::ostream& os, const void* buffer, std::size_t bufsize) {
  if (buffer == nullptr || bufsize == 0) return os;

  constexpr std::size_t maxline{16};

  // buffer for printable characters
  unsigned char  pbuf[maxline + 1]; // NOLINT
  unsigned char* pbuf_curr{pbuf};   // NOLINT

  const unsigned char* buf{reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(buffer)}; // NOLINT

  // pre-buffer area: floor(nearest maxline)
  size_t      offset    = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(buffer) % maxline; // NOLINT
  std::size_t linecount = maxline;
  if (offset > 0) {
    const void* prebuf = buf - offset; // NOLINT
    print_ptr(os, prebuf) << ": ";
    while (offset--) { // underflow OK NOLINT
      os << "-- ";
      *pbuf_curr++ = '.'; // NOLINT
      --linecount;
    }
  }

  // main buffer area
  while (bufsize) {                                    // NOLINT
    if (pbuf_curr == pbuf) print_ptr(os, buf) << ": "; // NOLINT
    print_byte(os, buf);
    *pbuf_curr++ = std::isprint(*buf) ? *buf : '.'; // NOLINT
    if (--linecount == 0) {
      *pbuf_curr++ = '\0';         // NOLINT
      os << " | " << pbuf << '\n'; // NOLINT
      pbuf_curr = pbuf;            // NOLINT
      linecount = std::min(maxline, bufsize);
    }
    --bufsize;
    ++buf; // NOLINT
  }

  // post buffer area: finish incomplete line
  if (pbuf_curr != pbuf) {                                                               // NOLINT
    for (*pbuf_curr++ = '\0'; pbuf_curr != &pbuf[maxline + 1]; ++pbuf_curr) os << "-- "; // NOLINT
    os << " | " << pbuf << '\n';                                                         // NOLINT
  }
  return os;
}

struct hd {
  const void* buffer;
  std::size_t bufsize;

  hd(const void* buf, std::size_t bufsz) : buffer{buf}, bufsize{bufsz} {}

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const hd& hd) {
    return hex_dump(out, hd.buffer, hd.bufsize);
  }
};

// start of demo/test

struct Dummy {
  int16_t a   = 0x1111; // forgive the ridiculous values, for easy spotting
  int32_t b   = 0x22222222;
  int32_t c   = 0x33333333;
  void*   ptr = (void*)0x8888888888888888; // crazy!
};

int main() {
  // Note on UB:
  // It's UB to access `+ 1`th byte of a sv or a str, but we know '\0'
  // is there in all these cases. Tthe point of using the hd() utility is to
  // examine these sorts of things during debugging so acceptably risky here?
  auto sv1 = std::string_view{"1234567890"}; // in .text (ie code) segment => non-aligned
  std::cout << hd(sv1.data(), sv1.size() + 1) << '\n';

  auto sv2 = std::string_view{"Hello there this is a much longer string"};
  std::cout << hd(sv2.data(), sv2.size() + 1) << '\n';  // starts on next byte after sv1

  auto str1 = std::string{"123456789012345"}; // SBO on stack => non-aligned
  std::cout << hd(str1.data(), str1.size() + 1) << '\n';

  auto str2 = std::string{"1234567890123456"}; // too big for SBO => on heap => 16Byte aligned
  std::cout << hd(str2.data(), str2.size() + 1) << '\n';

  auto d1 = Dummy{}; // on stack with alignment gaps
  std::cout << hd(&d1, sizeof(d1)) << '\n';

  auto d2 = std::make_unique<Dummy>(); // on heap with alignment gaps
  std::cout << hd(d2.get(), sizeof(*d2)) << '\n';

  auto d3 = std::make_unique<Dummy[]>(4); // array on heap: odd/even alignment NOLINT
  std::cout << hd(d3.get(), 4 * sizeof(d3[0])) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
           0x405000: -- -- -- -- 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 00 --  | ....1234567890.

           0x405000: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 48  | ...............H
           0x405010: 65 6c 6c 6f 20 74 68 65 72 65 20 74 68 69 73 20  | ello there this 
           0x405020: 69 73 20 61 20 6d 75 63 68 20 6c 6f 6e 67 65 72  | is a much longer
           0x405030: 20 73 74 72 69 6e 67 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  |  string.

     0x7ffe99b799f0: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38  | ........12345678
     0x7ffe99b79a00: 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | 9012345.

          0x131bec0: 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 36  | 1234567890123456
          0x131bed0: 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | .

     0x7ffe99b79950: 11 11 00 00 22 22 22 22 33 33 33 33 00 00 00 00  | ....""""3333....
     0x7ffe99b79960: 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | ........

          0x131bee0: 11 11 00 00 22 22 22 22 33 33 33 33 00 00 00 00  | ....""""3333....
          0x131bef0: 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | ........

          0x131bf00: 11 11 00 00 22 22 22 22 33 33 33 33 00 00 00 00  | ....""""3333....
          0x131bf10: 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 11 11 00 00 22 22 22 22  | ............""""
          0x131bf20: 33 33 33 33 00 00 00 00 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88  | 3333............
          0x131bf30: 11 11 00 00 22 22 22 22 33 33 33 33 00 00 00 00  | ....""""3333....
          0x131bf40: 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 11 11 00 00 22 22 22 22  | ............""""
          0x131bf50: 33 33 33 33 00 00 00 00 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88  | 3333............
```

Comment: Very related: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165120/printing-hex-dumps-for-diagnostics

Comment: Yes, exactly, I linked to it at top and hopefully gave appropriate credit. This is a further development of the idea.

Comment: Just noticed after seeing what you linked.

Comment: Please stop editing your question. You have an answer now, and your edits may invalidate it. If any invalidation happens we will side with the answerer as posting a question prematurely is considered poor form. Thank you.

Comment: @Peilonrayz
I have been over this with someone else already. As soon as I received the answer I acknowledged it by upvoting it and have stopped making any changes. I cannot see when  someone "starts to write a question". So if your timeline shows that "I edited question" after answer received then I would ask you to consider that there such a thing as concurrent access ;-). And to be honest G.Sliepen, myself and a couple of others just play ping-pong around here. The rest is tumbleweed.

Comment: @Peilonrayz BTW I noticed you silently deleted our previous exchange. Nice.

Comment: @OliverSchonrock I didn't delete any of your comments. I don't understand why you seem to accuse me of random things. But honestly I don't care. Bye.

Comment: @Peilonrayz
Not Random. They are gone for me. Please stop interfering . Thank you. Good bye.

Comment: @Oliver, please don't make unfounded accusations.  You have no idea who deleted comments (and if the comments were no longer needed, then deleting was the Right Thing; comments are ephemeral, and anything of long-term value needs to be in the question or in an answer).

Comment: @TobySpeight Fair enough: Not proven You're right, could have been someone else. (although I would stand by my suspicion not being unfounded, there was a bit of history to that exchange). But it's over now and I don't mind at all. I do stand by my general point that this community is over-policed given the level of activity. All chiefs and no Indians -- all police and no protestors. You know what I mean. It just comes across as unwelcoming IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Usefulness

Looks useful, although you could achieve something similar with a debugger, which in the end is much more powerful. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233095/memory-dump-formatted-like-xxd-from-gdb) about making GDB give similar output.

## Make a C++20 version

Because the code would be much cleaner if you could use `std::format()`. You can make it backwards compatible by detecting if C++20 support is present, otherwise falling back to [fmtlib](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt).

## Consider making `hd()` take a reference

I think it would be much cleaner if `hd()` took a reference, and have the size default to the size of the type:

```
template<typename T>
hd(const T &buf, std::size_t bufsz = sizeof(T)): buffer{...}, bufsize{...} {}
```

And then you could use it like:

```
auto d1 = Dummy{};
std::cout << hd(d1) << '\n';
```

Of course, it gets a bit harder to use if you want to dump arbitrary memory, but it's a trade-off. I think it would benefit beginners, who may not know the size of types, or might easily make mistakes like writing `hd(some_pointer, sizeof(some_pointer))`. Maybe have two distinct classes, or have a version that takes only a reference and no size, and one that takes a void pointer and a size.

## Avoid `void *` where possible

I think it's best if you cast to `unsigned char *` as soon as possible (in `hd`'s constructor), and stick with it. This avoids some casts in other parts of your code. The only time you want to cast it again is when printing the value of a pointer in `print_ptr()`.

Even better, use `std::byte *`, and only convert a `std::byte` to `char` when needing to print it as a character directly.

## Organizing the code

The function `hex_dump()` is a bit messy. It would be nicer if it was split into more functions, delegating more work to `print_*()` functions. In particular, have `print_bytes()` take a length so it prints a range of bytes in one go. Add a `print_ascii()` that prints a range of bytes as printable ASCII characters.

You could move the handling of the pre- and post-buffer area to the `print_*()` functions, avoiding the special-casing in `hex_dump()` itself. For example:

```
constexpr std::size_t linesize{16};
auto buf{buffer};
size_t pre = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(buffer) % maxline; // Size of pre-buffer area
buf -= pre; // Align buf and bufsize to start of pre-buffer area
bufsize += pre;

while (bufsize) {
    // Calculate the length of the post-buffer area on this line
    size_t post = bufsize < linesize ? linesize - bufsize : 0;

    // Print the line
    print_ptr(os, buf);
    os << ": ";
    print_bytes(os, buf, linesize, pre, post);
    os << " | ";
    print_ascii(os, buf, linesize, pre, post);
    os << "\n";

    buf += linesize;
    bufsize -= linesize - post; // Advance to next line, avoiding wrapping
    pre = 0;                    // No pre-buffer area after first line
}
```

## About printing pointers

I can think of use cases where you'd want to see the pointers as decimal values, possibly even just offsets from the start of the data instead of absolute values. Perhaps this could be made configurable?

## Make `bufsize_` `const`

Just as `buffer_` is `const`, you can make `bufsize_` `const` as well.

## Implications of using a class instead of a function

Using a class that has an `operator<<()` overload is a way to get relatively optimized output to an `std::ostream`, but there are some consequences. First, the class holds references to the data that is to be printed, and there is no guarantee that the data will be valid at the time you actually print it. For example, I could write:

```
hd bad_hd() {
    int i = 0xbad;
    return hd(&i, sizeof i);
}
...
std::cout << bad_hd(); // UB
```

This is a similar to how `std::span` behaves. While in the above it is rather obvious you are taking a reference of a local variable, it is harder to see if you have an overload that takes a reference of an arbitrary type. If you would use a function instead (basically `hex_dump()`, possibly with overloads), you would not have this issue.

The second issue, which is very minor but might surprise someone, is that you can't use `hd()` to print an instance of itself using the reference template overload:

```
int foo = 0xf00;
auto foo_hd = hd(foo);
std::cout << foo_hd; // OK
std::cout << hd(foo_hd); // Prints a copy of the above
std::cout << hd(&foo_hd, sizeof foo_hd); // Works
```

Comment: Great stuff as usual. 2 things. 1. I struggled to get anything much to work with std::byte (due to amount of weird recasting here). I will try again.  and 2. That's a good link to gdb post. I suspected some "scripting" could do that. TBH I find gdb (and any debugger even the IDE ones) to be a pain. It takes me so long to get set up the way I want it, and I need to so rarely that in 99.9% of cases it's faster to "print and think". What do you find?

Comment: It depends. Sure, it's easy to just add a print-statement here and there (and I do this too often myself), but then you need to recompile and rerun your program, and maybe you forgot to add a print-statement or made another mistake, and then you have to repeat the process, and in the end it would've been faster if you'd used the debugger from the beginning. It's definitely worth it to learn how to use one. Don't try too hard to get it to set it up the way you want it, learn how it works out of the box first.

Comment: Yeah. I do that. I am not too bad at gdb. I just find too many commands are required. Breakpoints, steps into out of, watches "examines" etc ...Oh now I need to recompile with `-O0` because the variable has been optimised out. By that stage I have solved it by thinking carefully about targeted prints and recompiling once. Mind you my compile times tend to be measured in seconds, not minutes. It's horses for course really. I find 99% I am in the print world.

Comment: I really liked your "use a reference" idea so the type gets pushed through and we can template detect it.  Tried to make it work. hmmmm.. sort of ...it never really detects the correct size. Like for none of the examples I gave. It gets the size of stack object. It would work for primitive types i think (bit boring), but that's about all.  Am I doing something differently to what you had in mind?

Comment: About the "correct" size: it depends on what you want. If I have some POD class I want to dump exactly that, and then `sizeof(T)` is what you want. But if you want it to print the dynamically allocated parts of a container, then you'd have to specify the size and right pointer manually. Or... you could add some SFINAE overloads to make it detect if `T::data()` and `T::size()` exist and then use those?

Comment: OK, yes. I will see if "guestimating" can work in a sufficient number of cases. Or is the very fact that you are looking at memory layout really asking that you understand which memory and how much of it, is sort of a prerequisite? ... Will think. Trying to refactor `hex_dump()` as suggest now. Second pair of eyes always useful. Thank you. ... You got me concerned about debuggers, but it appears I am not alone: https://lemire.me/blog/2016/06/21/i-do-not-use-a-debugger/

Comment: refactor went well. thanks. On "reference": I am going down a double route. Keep the 2 param (ptr and size) approach as  "power tool" and have a templated reference single param overload for which we have complete template specialisations for common non-trivial types, eg:   `template <typename T>
  explicit hd(const T& buf) : buffer{&buf}, bufsize{sizeof(T)} {}`

`template <>
  explicit hd(const std::string_view& buf) : buffer{buf.data()}, bufsize{buf.size() + 1} {}`
The unspecialiased version handles `int` etc. I am considering doing 2 dumps for std::string: stack part / heap part.

Comment: refactored version below incorporating your input and extending the concept of references for multi-part objects. Any feedback on the chaining of `hd` objects using `unique_ptr` appreciated. Wasn't 100% sure this is the best way, but could find a better one; `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper>` ??

Answer (score 2):

A refactored improved version taking on board many of the points from [@G.Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236042/212940) and then building on them:

- No more `void*` except for the general form `ctor` of `hd`
- Main function `hex_dump()` totally refactored. Better.
- `hd` ctor now has 2 overloads.

There is a general form of hd ctor with `(adr, size)` and then a templated form which takes a reference. The general for of that template calls `sizeof()` and uses `&var` for the address.

But there are also specialisations for `std::string_view` and `std::string` which:

1. do the same as the general form (gives the stack part of the obj)
2. Then chain a new instance of hd for the heap part of the object

I am still validating this design. It seems to work fine. Feedback welcome. When bedded down, I should be able to extend it to say `std::vector`: Printing the stack and heaps parts of the container. It might even be able to recurse down multiple layers.

New code and output below.

**Small surprise**: libstd++ uses 32bytes of stack for a heap allocated string? A `.data()` ptr a `size()` and another size which turns out to be the `.capacity()`. The remaining 8 bytes are alignment junk? Anyway we adjusted code to show the whole `capacity` of buffer which has been `reserved()`. Not just the current `size()`.

```
#include <bits/stdint-intn.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// utility: keeps states of an ostream, restores on destruction
template <typename T>
struct ostream_state {
  explicit ostream_state(std::basic_ostream<T>& stream)
      : stream_{stream}, flags_{stream.flags()}, fill_{stream.fill()} {}

  ostream_state(const ostream_state& other) = delete;
  ostream_state& operator=(const ostream_state& other) = delete;

  ostream_state(ostream_state&& other) = delete;
  ostream_state& operator=(ostream_state&& other) = delete;

  ~ostream_state() {
    stream_.flags(flags_);
    stream_.fill(fill_);
  }

private:
  std::basic_ostream<T>&                    stream_;
  std::ios_base::fmtflags                   flags_;
  typename std::basic_ostream<T>::char_type fill_;
};

namespace detail {
inline void print_adr(std::ostream& os, const std::byte* adr) {
  os << std::setw(19) << std::setfill(' ') << adr; // NOLINT
}

inline void print_fill_advance(std::ostream& os, const std::byte*& buf, std::size_t cnt,
                               const std::string& str) {
  while (cnt-- != 0U) {
    ++buf; // NOTE: unusually this in passsed in by ref and we advance it. NOLINT
    os << str;
  }
}

inline void print_hex(std::ostream& os, const std::byte* buf, std::size_t linesize, std::size_t pre,
                      std::size_t post) {
  print_fill_advance(os, buf, pre, "-- ");
  {
    os << std::setfill('0') << std::hex;
    auto cnt = linesize - pre - post;
    while (cnt-- != 0U) os << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(*buf++) << ' '; // NOLINT
  }
  print_fill_advance(os, buf, post, "-- ");
}

inline void print_ascii(std::ostream& os, const std::byte* buf, std::size_t linesize,
                        std::size_t pre, std::size_t post) {
  print_fill_advance(os, buf, pre, ".");
  auto cnt = linesize - pre - post;
  while (cnt-- != 0U) {
    os << (std::isprint(static_cast<unsigned char>(*buf)) != 0 ? static_cast<char>(*buf) : '.');
    ++buf; // NOLINT
  }
  print_fill_advance(os, buf, post, ".");
}
} // namespace detail

inline std::ostream& hex_dump(std::ostream& os, const std::byte* buffer, std::size_t bufsize) {
  if (buffer == nullptr || bufsize == 0) return os;

  constexpr std::size_t linesize{16};
  const std::byte*      buf{buffer};
  std::size_t           pre =
      reinterpret_cast<std::size_t>(buffer) % linesize; // Size of pre-buffer area  NOLINT
  bufsize += pre;
  buf -= pre; // NOLINT

  auto state = ostream_state{os}; // save stream setting and restore at end of scope
  while (bufsize != 0U) {
    std::size_t post = bufsize < linesize ? linesize - bufsize : 0;

    detail::print_adr(os, buf);
    os << ": ";
    detail::print_hex(os, buf, linesize, pre, post);
    os << " | ";
    detail::print_ascii(os, buf, linesize, pre, post);
    os << "\n";

    buf += linesize; // NOLINT
    bufsize -= linesize - post;
    pre = 0;
  }
  return os;
}

class hd {
public:
  hd(const void* buf, std::size_t bufsz)
      : buffer_{reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(buf)}, bufsize_{bufsz} {}

  template <typename T>
  explicit hd(const T& buf)
      : buffer_{reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(&buf)}, bufsize_{sizeof(T)} {}

  // It's UB to access `+ 1`th byte of a string_view so we don't, despite most
  // targets of string_views (ie std::string or string literal) having '\0'.
  template <>
  explicit hd(const std::string_view& buf)
      : buffer_{reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(&buf)}, bufsize_{sizeof(buf)} {
    child_       = std::make_unique<hd>(buf.data(), buf.size());
    child_label_ = "string viewed";
  }

  // There is some debate but we believe str[size()] is legal via [] or *
  // but UB via iterator. So here we DO show the '`0' terminator.
  template <>
  explicit hd(const std::string& buf)
      : buffer_{reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(&buf)}, bufsize_{sizeof(buf)} {
    auto data_byte_ptr = reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(buf.data());
    if (!(data_byte_ptr > buffer_ && data_byte_ptr < buffer_ + bufsize_)) {
      // not SBO, show the real string as well
      child_ = std::make_unique<hd>(buf.data(), buf.size() + 1);
      child_label_ = "heap string";
    }
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const hd& hd) {
    hex_dump(os, hd.buffer_, hd.bufsize_); // NOLINT
    if (hd.child_) os << std::setw(19) << hd.child_label_ << ":\n" << *(hd.child_);
    return os;
  }

private:
  const std::byte* buffer_;
  std::size_t      bufsize_;

  std::unique_ptr<hd> child_ = nullptr;
  std::string         child_label_;
};

// start of demo/test

struct Dummy {
  int16_t a      = 0x1111;
  int32_t b      = 0x22222222;
  int32_t c      = 0x33333333;
  void*   end    = (void*)0xffffffffffffffff; // NOLINT end of earth
};

int main() {
  auto i1 = int{0x12345678}; // 4 bytes int, 4-byte aligned
  std::cout << os::hd(i1) << '\n';

  auto pi = 22/7.0; // 8bytes on stack
  std::cout << os::hd(pi) << '\n';

  auto sv1 = std::string_view{"1234567890"}; // in .text (ie code) segment => non-aligned
  std::cout << os::hd(sv1) << '\n';

  auto sv2 = std::string_view{"This is a much longer string view onto a string literal"};
  std::cout << os::hd(sv2) << '\n'; // starts after sv1 with '\0' gap

  auto i2 = short{0x1234};  // 2 bytes int, 4-byte aligned
  std::cout << os::hd(i2) << '\n';

  auto str1 = std::string{"123456789012345"}; // SBO on stack => 16-byte aligned??
  std::cout << os::hd(str1) << '\n';

  auto str2 = std::string{"1234567890123456"}; // too big for SBO => on heap => 16Byte aligned
  std::cout << os::hd(str2) << '\n';

  auto d1 = Dummy{}; // on stack 8-byte aligned with padding gaps
  std::cout << os::hd(d1) << '\n';

  auto d2 = std::make_unique<Dummy>(); // on heap 16byte aligned with padding gaps
  std::cout << os::hd(d2.get(), sizeof(*d2)) << '\n';

  auto d3 = std::make_unique<Dummy[]>(4); // array on heap 8-byte aligned: odd/even NOLINT
  std::cout << os::hd(d3.get(), 4 * sizeof(d3[0])) << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
     0x7ffcb8d3d350: -- -- -- -- 78 56 34 12 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | ....xV4.........

     0x7ffcb8d3d370: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 49 92 24 49 92 24 09 40  | ........I.$I.$.@

     0x7ffcb8d3d3a0: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  | ................
     0x7ffcb8d3d3b0: 42 66 42 00 00 00 00 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | BfB.............
      string viewed:
           0x426640: -- -- 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 -- -- -- --  | ..1234567890....

     0x7ffcb8d3d390: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 37 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  | ........7.......
     0x7ffcb8d3d3a0: 4d 66 42 00 00 00 00 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | MfB.............
      string viewed:
           0x426640: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 54 68 69  | .............Thi
           0x426650: 73 20 69 73 20 61 20 6d 75 63 68 20 6c 6f 6e 67  | s is a much long
           0x426660: 65 72 20 73 74 72 69 6e 67 20 76 69 65 77 20 6f  | er string view o
           0x426670: 6e 74 6f 20 61 20 73 74 72 69 6e 67 20 6c 69 74  | nto a string lit
           0x426680: 65 72 61 6c -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | eral............

     0x7ffcb8d3d320: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 34 12  | ..............4.

     0x7ffcb8d3d330: 40 d3 d3 b8 fc 7f 00 00 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  | @...............
     0x7ffcb8d3d340: 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 00  | 123456789012345.

     0x7ffcb8d3d350: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 90 f8 e1 01 00 00 00 00  | ................
     0x7ffcb8d3d360: 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  | ................
     0x7ffcb8d3d370: 08 e0 04 eb 00 7f 00 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | ................
        heap string:
          0x1e1f890: 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 36  | 1234567890123456
          0x1e1f8a0: 00 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | ................

     0x7ffcb8d3d380: 11 11 42 00 22 22 22 22 33 33 33 33 00 00 00 00  | ..B.""""3333....
     0x7ffcb8d3d390: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | ................

          0x1e1f910: 11 11 00 00 22 22 22 22 33 33 33 33 00 00 00 00  | ....""""3333....
          0x1e1f920: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | ................

          0x1e11eb0: 11 11 00 00 22 22 22 22 33 33 33 33 00 00 00 00  | ....""""3333....
          0x1e11ec0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 11 11 00 00 22 22 22 22  | ............""""
          0x1e11ed0: 33 33 33 33 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  | 3333............
          0x1e11ee0: 11 11 00 00 22 22 22 22 33 33 33 33 00 00 00 00  | ....""""3333....
          0x1e11ef0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 11 11 00 00 22 22 22 22  | ............""""
          0x1e11f00: 33 33 33 33 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  | 3333............
```

Comment: Nice refactoring! I noticed you can `static_cast<>()` a `void *` to a `std::byte *` instead of using a `reinterpret_cast<>()`. Also, in the loop in `print_ascii()`, you could write `auto c = std::to_integer<char>(*buf++); os << (std::isprint(c) ? c : '.')` (you need to `#include <cstddef>`). Using `std::unique_ptr<hd> child_` is interesting, but why not just have two `buffer` and `bufsize` variables, and call `hex_dump()` twice in `operator<<()`? This avoids memory allocations.

Comment: @G.Sliepen
Thanks. Good call on static_cast (only for the general ctor though). And good call on std::to_integer. Wasn't aware of that. But is it correct? Not UB? I thought `isprint` needs `unsigned char` to be non-UB?

Comment: @G.Sliepen On chaining: I agree the allocation is slightly irritating. I might go three levels though or even recursive so that the idea of a straight "clone" of the object "and recurse"  (sort of, not quite yet) appealed to me. The only other solution I thought of was to give hd() a default ctor. Then "empty - value initalialised" could mean "no child" (with nullptr / zero), and then you popluate it if you need it...? That way we always get an extra (often uneeded) hd obj, but that's cheap? --- I have done a std::vector version too. These are quite trivial to add.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Since you are the casting expert, do you have ideas on my `char*` struggles? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236073/c-wrapper-for-graphviz-library/236079 See comments under first answer for more details.

Comment: You're right apparently about `std::isprint()` needing an `unsigned char`, although in practice I've never seen any code casting a `char` to `unsigned char` before using any of the `ctype.h` functions. But better safe than sorry. You can't have a `hd` object directly embedded in `hd` itself, it always has to be a pointer, so then using `std::unique_ptr` is the right thing to do.

Comment: Yeah the `unsigned char` thing is annoying. Especially since I don't even remotely understand why? You're right of course about `hd` having an `hd` member or even a `std::optional<hd>`. It can't work....incomplete object stuff. forgot :-)

Comment: It's not only that it's incomplete, it's also because it would recurse infinitely!

Comment: @G.Sliepen not the way I had it laid out in my head...but anyway it's a mute point. can't put "self members", the language just doesn't support without boost::container (or whatever that thing is called). The recursion stop challenge exists with the pointer too. I will cross that bridge when I get a real world example of 3+ layer object dumping.