# C++ wrapper for graphviz library

Tags: c++, strings, api

### Background

The code below is (obviously minimally) ripped out of a current live project. The project does reasonably sized data extraction, cleaning, analysis, clustering and visualisation (on a budget, and that's why we are not using graphistry or similar for the visualisation part).

So for our sins, we are using [graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/)'s very mature `neato` engine which implements the Kamada Kawai algorithm which has been shown to work well for our purpose (after researching many many algorithms), although it does not scale very well. We chose to interface with graphviz rather than use the [Boost Graph Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.html). (possibly a mistake).

For this code review I am going to focus on a slim slice, which is the `C++` wrapper class of the graphviz lib. And specifically on one aspect of that. How to sanely and safely interface with the many many `char*` params which the C-API expects.

### Your friend the `char*`

I have included the (slimmed down) wrapper class below together with an improvised `main()` to show usage. The wrapper just does RAII and "method => function shoveling".

Most of graphviz's API uses `char*`. Are they `const` (i.e. are they modified when we call their API)? Who knows. They don't appear to get modified, but without reading all their source, we can't know for sure.

Do we want `const std::string&` or `std::string_view` or even, at worst `const char*` APIs? Yes we do.

We pass in a bunch of string (sorry `char*`) constants for attributes and colour names etc, small sample below.

The code as shown works fine. It's messy, I don't like it, because it uses a bunch of C-Style casts to cast away the `constness`. Yes I could use `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` or `const_cast` for some of these cases. Very painful syntax. In this encapsulated API I choose the C-style casts for terseness.

### Is it safe and correct?

What's worse is that I believe the behaviour is not super well defined when using `std:string_view`. I have chosen `std::string_view` as my C++-end API type for all those mini-strings. There are several possible alternatives, I tried a few, but this seems reasonable given I need to store C++-end tables of, for example, colour constants (see short extract in code). -- `std::string` seems like heavy overkill here.

But `std::string_view` should not be passed to a `char*` because it is not guaranteed to terminate with `'\0'`. -- maybe that's not UB, but it's potentially bad! So does that eliminate the otherwise possibly best solution  we have in modern C++?

As I said it works fine, because *I know* that all the strings end with `'\0'`, but it doesn't make me happy.

### Feedback wanted.

- General on legacy C-API encapsulation class
- Specifically on this option and alternatives for the `char*` API - Is my best option to deal with `[const] char*` in C++ too, rather than `std::string_view`?

```
#include <cgraph.h> // these 2 includes are the graphiz cgraph lib
#include <gvc.h>

#include <array>

using size_t = std::size_t;

class Graph {
public:
  Graph() {
    gvc_ = gvContext();

    static const char* fargv[] = {"neato", "-Tsvg"}; // NOLINT
    gvParseArgs(gvc_, 2, (char**)fargv);             // NOLINT

    graph_ = agopen((char*)"g", Agundirected, nullptr); // NOLINT

    // clang-format off
    set_graph_attr_def("splines",   "none");
    set_graph_attr_def("ratio",     "1.25");

    set_node_attr_def("tooltip",    "");
    set_node_attr_def("fillcolor",  "grey");
    set_node_attr_def("shape",      "point");
    set_node_attr_def("width",      "0.05");
    set_node_attr_def("penwidth",   "0");

    set_edge_attr_def("weight",     "1");
    // clang-format on
  }

  Graph(const Graph& other) = delete;
  Graph& operator=(const Graph& other) = delete;

  Graph(Graph&& other) = delete;
  Graph& operator=(Graph&& other) = delete;

  ~Graph() {
    if (graph_ != nullptr) {
      if (gvc_ != nullptr) gvFreeLayout(gvc_, graph_);
      agclose(graph_);
    }
    if (gvc_ != nullptr) gvFreeContext(gvc_);
  }

  void set_graph_attr_def(std::string_view name, std::string_view value) {
    agattr(graph_, AGRAPH, (char*)name.data(), (char*)value.data()); // NOLINT
  }

  void set_node_attr_def(std::string_view name, std::string_view value) {
    agattr(graph_, AGNODE, (char*)name.data(), (char*)value.data()); // NOLINT
  }

  void set_edge_attr_def(std::string_view name, std::string_view value) {
    agattr(graph_, AGEDGE, (char*)name.data(), (char*)value.data()); // NOLINT
  }

  void set_node_attr(Agnode_t* node, std::string_view name, std::string_view value) { // NOLINT
    agset(node, (char*)name.data(), (char*)value.data());                             // NOLINT
  }

  void set_edge_attr(Agedge_t* edge, std::string_view name, std::string_view value) { // NOLINT
    agset(edge, (char*)name.data(), (char*)value.data());                             // NOLIN
  }

  Agedge_t* add_edge(Agnode_t* src, Agnode_t* dest, std::string_view weight_str) {
    auto edge = agedge(graph_, src, dest, nullptr, 1);
    set_edge_attr(edge, "weight", weight_str);
    return edge;
  }

  Agnode_t* add_node(std::string_view node_name) {
    auto node = agnode(graph_, (char*)node_name.data(), 1); // NOLINT
    set_node_attr(node, "tooltip", node_name);
    return node;
  }

  void layout() {
    gvLayoutJobs(gvc_, graph_);
  }

  void render() {
    gvRenderJobs(gvc_, graph_);
  }

private:
  Agraph_t* graph_ = nullptr;
  GVC_t*    gvc_   = nullptr;
};

static constexpr const size_t max_colours = 30;

static constexpr const std::array<std::string_view, max_colours> colours = {
    "blue",           "green",         "red",        "gold",
    "black",          "magenta",       "brown",      "pink",
    "khaki",          "cyan",          "tan",        "blueviolet",
    "burlywood",      "cadetblue",     "chartreuse", "chocolate",
    "coral",          "darkgoldenrod", "darkgreen",  "darkkhaki",
    "darkolivegreen", "darkorange",    "darkorchid", "darksalmon",
    "darkseagreen",   "dodgerblue",    "lavender",   "mediumpurple",
    "plum",           "yellow"};

int main() {
  auto graph = Graph{}; // initializes instace of a graphviz graph

  // build node list by loading data from a mongo database

  auto node1 = graph.add_node("1");
  auto node2 = graph.add_node("2");
  // ...  10,000 + nodes  (that's all neato can handle, we would like more)

  // 2.3 is the "weight" and it's a double in our code but graphiz wants a string
  // there is a reason that the Graph::add_edge API takes the string
  // the double -> string conversion is quite expensive (we use Ryu)
  // and we need it twice. Once for graphviz and once for the cluster
  // both as a string
  graph.add_edge(node1, node2, "2.3");
  //... 2 - 25 million edges

  // run clustering algorithm on separate thread

  graph.layout(); // graphviz neato: slowest part of whole program

  // clustering has finished by now, update the colours
  graph.set_node_attr(node1, "fillcolor", colours[0]); // NOLINT
  graph.set_node_attr(node1, "fillcolor", colours[1]); // NOLINT
  // ...

  graph.render(); // sends svg to stdout
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to where I can get the header files?

Comment: http://graphviz.org/download/

Comment: The graph class is following a Facade Pattern, you can do real conversions within each function, up to and including char* = new char[type.size+];.

Comment: Just passing by, looking for a graphviz C++ library myself. What I'd do in the above code is add, at the very least, asserts that check if the terminating zero is there: `assert(is_zero_terminated(name))`.

Comment: @CarloWood How can you check that without reading the string char by char (or directly the one past the end if you know the length).. and if it isn't null terminated then you have just accessed out of bounds and have UB?

Comment: Correct on the UB, but it will crash or assert in that case in the assert - better than to pass a non-null terminated string on the rest of the code. And you know the length, you have a string_view. PS I am working on https://github.com/CarloWood/cppgraphviz since two days now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few things that may help you improve your program.

### Reconsider the tool

The `graphviz` package seems designed for more human-scale output graphics than your project is intending to use.  The problem, as you have discovered, is that the layout does not scale linearly with the number of nodes, so your desire to process more than 10,000 nodes and millions of edges might not be a good match for `graphviz`, or for human consumption as a single diagram.  Might GIS software such as GRASS or QGIS might be more appropriate for your use?

### Use a different layout engine

The `neato` engine has limitations that the `sfdp` engine does not.  If you change

```
static const char* fargv[] = {"neato", "-Tsvg"}; // NOLINT
```

to this:

```
static const char* fargv[] = {"sfdp", "-Tsvg"}; // NOLINT
```

the layout will be a bit different, but perhaps still acceptable and likely faster.

### Check the fine print

You may already be aware, but in fact, the `dot` requires the [weights to be integer values](http://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:weight).  For the reasons mentioned in the comments of your code, you may not want to change anything anyway, but it's probably useful to be aware of it and maybe also insert a comment saying "yes, I know" if that's the case.

Comment: thanks! I tried `sfdp` it's much faster than `neato`, but the layout is next to useless for our purposes. I haven't tried "geo type" type software as this is not geo info, and I didn't make this link. This is company data, for researchers to spot clusters of companies. Not sure if that will fit, but I'll look into it. We looked at `open-ord`, which is very fast, but useless layout for us. Fruchterman-Reingold is good, but not faster than Kamada Kawai (neato).

Comment: We can "layout, cluster and render" 10,000 nodes in a "reasonable" < 1min for the complete process. So what we do when we have more data, is we "random sample it" and then "zoom in on interesting clusters".  I agree the docs say "`dot` expects integers" , but `neato` seems to work well with `float`s. Is there a possible performance gain with `int`s? I don't know, haven't tried that. But I am always open to new ideas for engines. The clustering algo we use is written in java and it is lightning fast. So we just call it with `pstream`. No point rewriting it.

Comment: This post here was mostly about the annoying `char*` interface. And I solved that after getting some ideas from SO: See comments under here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59902007/c-wrapper-for-c-api-exploring-best-options-for-passing-char/59903547#59903547

Comment: I tried it and noticed no difference with integers vs. float with `neato` in terms of either layout or performance, but I didn't look very closely.  As for the suspected UB, it seemed to me that you have a usable answer.  I'd consider re-implementing the Kamanda Kawai algorithm if performance is critical and `graphviz` is not delivering.  Like you, I generally prefer to recycle rather than reimplement, but sometimes it's needed.

Comment: Yes, many thanks for your time. I am currently looking into Boost graph who have a Kamada Kawei implementation. And there is some quite new research (from Asia I think) which seems to suggest that by chaining several of the historically known algorithms(tweaked a bit) you can get a 2 orders of magnitude gain. That would be great, but of course the whole thing is bascically O(n^2) so 2 orders is actually just 1, but still!

Answer (score 3):

Basically the code is well thought out and written.

A major observation about the code is that it is totally focused on performance/speed of execution, and not very flexible or extensible. A user of the graph class may want to add arguments to the `argv` through a call to a member function or an alternate version of the constructor that accepts a list of arguments. Hard coding the number of arguments in `arvg` (farvg) makes this impossible. It is very easy to calculate `argc` from `argv`:

```
        gvParseArgs(gvc_, sizeof(fargv)/ sizeof(*fargv), (char**)fargv);             // NOLINT
```

The  variable `fargv` might be made into a class member variable to allow extensibility.

The use of `std::array` over `std::vector` is another place where the code is not extensible. The use of `std::array` also forces the creation of a constant that is only used in the initialization of the array. I understand that the use of `std::vector` prevents the use of `constexpr` but I value extensibility over optimization. Some of us old school programs say that the first rule of optimization is *don't*. The real first rule is find the bottle necks before optimizing.

### Minor Nit

I generally put the closing `};` of an std::array or std::vector initialization on a new line that is indented to the beginning of the array, it makes it a little more readable and easier to edit.

```
static const std::vector<std::string_view> colours = {
        "blue",           "green",         "red",        "gold",
        "black",          "magenta",       "brown",      "pink",
        "khaki",          "cyan",          "tan",        "blueviolet",
        "burlywood",      "cadetblue",     "chartreuse", "chocolate",
        "coral",          "darkgoldenrod", "darkgreen",  "darkkhaki",
        "darkolivegreen", "darkorange",    "darkorchid", "darksalmon",
        "darkseagreen",   "dodgerblue",    "lavender",   "mediumpurple",
        "plum",           "yellow"
};
```

### Missing Header

Somehow `#include <string_view>` seems to have been dropped from the code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Which `#include` is missing? Your points are well made. Clearly the `fargs` thing is almost a "hack". The `cgraph` lib is tightly coupled to their command line programmes (`dot`, `neato` etc). So the way you "configure" the main instance is you call `gvParseArgs`. I find it a bit weird..?! Anyway my wrapper is not designed to be run by the user with command line args etc. It's spawned from another process and the mongodb query is piped in json format, etc etc. the real `argv[]` is not for graphviz. But that's what the lib gives me. So I hacked it for what I need.

Comment: I actually wasn't focused on performance. Well I am, but only in the very inner loop, which creates edges (2-250million of them). So you are suggesting that I should store the 200+ little colour constants  (above is just an extract) in a `std::vector<std::string>` ? As a static class member and then make the method APIs what? `std::string_view` or `const std::string&`?

Comment: many thanks for the #include...sorry about that

Comment: I would find it very difficult to count 200+ colors (us) and create a constant for them.

Comment: I can email you the list if you like....they exist... :-(

Comment: Thanks, but that would be a bit much. :)

Comment: But the main point is: What do we use? full `std::string` 's or `string literals` where appropriate. And how do we pass them to our C++ API: `std::string_view` `const std::string&` or `const char*`. Then how do we cast them to squeeze them into C's `char*`. What is the best "cast". Is it safe (null terminator, is it really `const` in the "C" lib etc). In my mind these are all, quite mundane and nit-picky questions, but they sort of matter. And they matter for anyone interfacing with "C". That's why I posted this.

Comment: If you pass const std::string& into the API you could use std::string.c_str() to get the const char *ptr. This would take care of the null termination as well.

Comment: Yes, halfway. It requires instantiating a static vector of 200 colour constants - feels crazy, but you're right, it shouldn't maybe... then I pass eveything as std::string on C++ side and it enters Graph API as `const std::string&`  (has to be this so it will accept a literal const rvalue ref). Then I call c_str() and it's `const` => need to cast it to `unconst`. You can call `.data()` which is `non-const` but it's only `non-const` if the std::string is `non-const`..except it is. so then we have this https://godbolt.org/z/MWmLHP and we still haven't solved it..without a potentially UB cast?

Comment: OH, re the brace positon. I don't disagree... But I use .clang-format, have tuned it to "close enough"..and it does it's thing. I format very few things by hand. I am too old for that.

Comment: I don't know what I can add but we can discuss it on https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor if you want.